# What should the input be to an image segmentation model?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I have come across articles about different image segmentation models. Few of them mention to use the masked version of the image to get semantic segmentation. I wanted to know, is masking necessary or that can be skipped while performing semantic segmentation using models like UNet.

Answer (score 0):

To train a basic semantic segmentation model, you need an image to input into the model and a 'mask' the size of the image that maps each pixel onto a class label.

For example if your 64x64 color input image [3,64,64] contains a bird flying in the sky, your 'mask' would be a [1,64,64] tensor with each element labeled either 1 => bird in this pixel or 0 => sky in this pixel.